# In Watson Discovery API, Which result shall i use to determine the most relevant documents: score or confidence?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I work on a Discovery collection on which i never made a training.
When i launch a natural language query on my collection, in the result_metadata of the retrieved documents, i see 2 notions: score and confidence
ex:
                "confidence": 0.0847209066468392,
                "score": 3.4830062
and the tag "retrieval_details" has the value   "document_retrieval_strategy": "untrained"

In the documentation, it is first written that "The confidence score will be returned for both trained and untrained private collections" and further that "The confidence score for a result with the document_retrieval_strategy of untrained is an unsupervised estimate of how relevant the document results are to the query; it is not interchangeable with the the score returned for trained collections. A trained collection can provide better answers to natural language queries than untrained collections."
Precisely: what does that mean ? How that confidence score is calculated ? Which result shall i use to get the most relevant documents : score or confidence ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use confidence. Score should never be used to define thresholds, since it’s a relative calculation.

It’s also recommended to use the “document_retrieval_strategy” as part of the thresholds, having a different threshold to each strategy, or at least one for trained and one for untrained, since the way confidence is treated will be different based on the strategy applied.

[This post](https://developer.ibm.com/watson/blog/2016/06/23/how-to-select-a-threshold-for-acting-using-confidence-scores/) can give you some ideas on how to define your threshold.